# li elements not created in foreach statement

Tags: html-lists, velocity

Is there a maximum number li elements in an OL or UL ?
I have a static UL and in a foreach I'm trying to add elements to the list. If I add more than 9 elements only first LI is created. I checked my list and I have all the elements in it and the foreach statement is executed to the last element.
If I replace LI with UL Li (instead of creating one list element I'm creating a new list of 1 element) then everything works fine.

Comment: do you have some working example?

Comment: There is no limit of li elements in a UL or OL ( the limit exist but is >1000000 ). The problem was another limitation in a .vm file. Thanks